# JMeter Constant Timer, Constant Throughput Timer

Tags: timer, jmeter

I am developing a JMeter Script according to the below requirement

Total Http Requests - 24,
Total Http Request/min - 12,
Test Duration 2min,
Waiting time between requests per minute : 60min/12req = 5sec .

In my scenario totally 3 transactions are happening

1. Add Document (20% of Total Requests)
2. Add Document (80% of Total Requests)
3. Update Documents (100% of Total Requests)

Below are the Thread Groups and Controllers that I have used

1. Ultimate Thread Group
   [Ultimate Thread Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X94f2.png)
2. (2) Throughput Controllers to distribute the load in Percent[20% and 80% of total 24 requests]
   [Throughput Controllers][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zres.png)
3. Transaction Controller to Update Document
4. Constant Timers for Each HTTP Request to wait between the requests (Constant timers have been given 5000ms of wait time)
5. (3) Constant Throughput Controllers to limit the number of requests per minute. Requests per minutes are mentioned as below
        (1st - 3req, 2nd - 9 req, 3rd - 12req -----> Total 24 Requests per 2 minutes)

But my problem is, I cannot get the Throughput as I have mentioned above

Below is my developed script

[Developed JMeter Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJyct.png)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have different throughputs for different Samplers (requests) in the same [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group), all requests will be executed **at the speed of the slowest request**.

The only way to execute different [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) at different rate is moving them to different Thread Groups.

If you need to pass data between different thread groups there are following options available:

- [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function to set the value in one Thread Group and [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function to read the value in another Thread Group
- [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/)